# How to get PM2 to watch for changes in Vagrant's shared directory?

Tags: vagrant, pm2

I am using [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html) `1.8.1` and [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) `5.0.16r105871` and provisioning a `ubuntu/wily64` box. I installed Node `4.4.3` on the guest. I use the following process to get the server up and running.

```
cd /vagrant
npm install
npm install -g pm2
pm2 startup ubuntu
sudo su -c "env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin pm2 startup ubuntu -u vagrant"
pm2 start process.json
pm2 save
```

I tried starting PM2 using the `--watch` option be that didn't work.
I tried using PM2 process configuration but it only works if I touch files while on the guest machine.

```
{
  "apps": [{
    "name": "mean-boilerplate",
    "script": "index.js",
    "watch": ["index.js"],
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "development",
    }
  }]
}
```

Any ideas how to get this working with PM2? Or should I be using a different method/module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usePolling option made the watch functionality work for me when I needed to watch folders that reside on the host but are mounted in the Vagrant VM (like the shared directory). Try adding it like this to your JSON config:

```
{
  "apps": [{
    "name": "mean-boilerplate",
    "script": "index.js",
    "watch" : ["index.js"],
    "watch_options" : {"usePolling": true},
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "development",
    }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems but now I've solved.

I'm using vagrant 2.2.0 and using ubuntu/xenial64 box (current version is 16.04).

At first, I tried to add this option

```
"watch_options" : {"usePolling": true},
```

There is more options related with the polling timing (interval and binaryInterval) (ref: https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar#api).

As the default interval is too fast, someone advised to set more loose interval.

But, even though I set the sufficient interval, pm2 consumes too much computer resources and my computer fan throttling.

There are already issue https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1314

I don't know exactly why usePolling is inefficient. But as the author says that usePolling **watch files over the a network**, I think it would be the reason of the problem, I guess.

So, I discard the usePolling options, and find another way to notify the file change from host to guest machine.

The solution I found is, use the **'vagrant-fsnotify'** plugin. https://github.com/adrienkohlbecker/vagrant-fsnotify

The plugin usage is well descripted in the readme page.

The result is? Successful. I didn't monitor the hardware resource, but as my fan silence, I think it is solved.